# Borel set and Lebesgue

Tags: lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Can someone help me with this problem: We have to show that E=$⋃^∞_1[n,n+1/3^n$] is a borel set and we have to find $\lambda(E)$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is the countable union of measurable sets it is measurable. For its measure, just compute the sum of the lengths of each interval, they are disjoint.